# how to properly update datasource when inserting and deleting rows from UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to delete some rows from UITableView and here is my code...

```
    [self.responsesTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.responsesTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.processingIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self. responsesTableView endUpdates];
    noOfRsponses --;
    if (self.segFrndEveryone.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [self.arrFriendComments removeObjectAtIndex:self.processingIndexPath.row];
    }else {
        [self.arrAllComments removeObjectAtIndex:self.processingIndexPath.row];
    }
```

where one of the two arrays is my datasource depnding on the segment selected. 
I am getting the following error and not sure how to deal with this.

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
>   (9) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
>   before the update (9), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or
>   deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus
>   the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0
>   moved out).'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the removeObjectAtIndex on the correct array?  Based on the error message, you haven't actually removed an object from the datasource that the tableview is expecting you to have removed from.  I'm guessing that maybe you are removing from the wrong array.

And one other thing to try:  remove the object first and then do the deleteRowsAtIndexPath.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but now the message has changed to this... Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (8) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (9), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Comment: Fixed it... silly error. (was also returning the no of responses in the no of sections... :X)

Answer (score 3):

You should update your data source before making manual changes to the `UITableView`.

```
// update the data source for the table change
noOfRsponses--;
NSMutableArray *targetArray = (self.segFrndEveryone.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? self.arrFriendComments : self.arrAllComments;
[targetArray removeObjectAtIndex:self.processingIndexPath.row];

// update the table view itself
[[self responsesTableView] beginUpdates];
[[self responsesTableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.processingIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[[self responsesTableView] endUpdates];
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but now the message has changed to this... Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (8) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (9), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Comment: The error message reports that you have an invalid number of *sections* after the update of a *row* causing me to wonder whether there's a second issue here.  By any chance, is the row you are deleting the only row in that section?

Answer (score 0):

You should use methods for sections

```
- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```